# Node JS Maria DB Bulk Insert Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mariadb, bulkinsert

I'm trying to bulk insert products in database, it seems to be working as it's not throwing any error but it's only inserting the first values array from the array. When I check with console.log, the array returns multiple arrays but only one is being inserted. Any idea where could this come from? Thanks a lot in advance!

```
const pool = mariadb.createPool({
     ...
     multipleStatements: true
});
var conn = pool.getConnection();

var matchedProducts = [];
for (var ptm_i = 0; ptm_i < products_to_match.length; ptm_i++) {

                                value_to_add = products_to_match[ptm_i]['suid'];
                                var final_price = products_to_match[ptm_i]['finalprice']/100;
                                var initial_price = products_to_match[ptm_i]['price']/100;
                                var isOnSale = products_to_match[ptm_i]['onsale'];
                                var sizes = unique_id_sizes[value_to_add].join(',');
                                var store_details = [
                                    products_to_match[ptm_i]['product_id'],
                                    partner_id,
                                    final_price,
                                    initial_price,
                                    isOnSale,
                                    'USD',
                                    sizes,
                                    value_to_add,
                                    products_to_match[ptm_i]['id'],
                                    products_to_match[ptm_i]['url']
                                ];
                                matchedProducts.push(store_details);
                            }       
                            //console.log(matchedProducts);
                            try{                    
                                let matched_query = 'INSERT INTO stores (product_id, partner_id, price, initial_price, is_on_sale, currency, sizes, merchant_code, origin_id, link) VALUES ?';
                                conn.query(matched_query, matchedProducts, (error, result) => {
                                    //console.log(result);
                                });

                            }catch(err){
                                console.log(err)
                                throw err;
                            }
}
```

Comment: you're just using the wrong method. added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the `mariadb` connector here.

To insert by batch you use:

```
connection.batch(sql, values) → Promise: fast batch processing.
```

not

```
connection.query(sql[, values]) → Promise: Executes a query.
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-nodejs/blob/master/documentation/promise-api.md#connectionbatchsql-values--promise).

Here is an example:

```
// https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-nodejs/blob/master/documentation/batch.md
connection.beginTransaction();
connection.query("INSERT INTO BASKET(customerId) values (?)", [1], (err, res) => {
  //must handle error if any
  const basketId = res.insertId;
  try {
    connection.batch("INSERT INTO basket_item(basketId, itemId) VALUES (?, ?)",[
        [basketId, 100],
        [basketId, 101],
        [basketId, 103],
        [basketId, 104],
        [basketId, 105]
    ]);
    //must handle error if any
    connection.commit();
  } catch (err) {
    connection.rollback();
    //handle error
  }
});
```

Comment: Used .batch instead of .query and it's now working. Thanks a lot!